# Datatables show the ajax data but blank when I search the data and the data is not listed in info

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I am currently having trouble with datatables, when the data is hardcoded int HTML the table is searchable, but when I get from ajax, the data is showed but after I type from search input, the data disappears.

here is the code :

````js
```(function($) {


    'use strict';

    var responsiveHelper = undefined;
    var breakpointDefinition = {
        tablet: 1024,
        phone: 480
    };

    // Initialize datatable showing a search box at the top right corner
    var initTableWithSearch = function() {
        var table = $('#tableWithSearch');

        var settings = {
            "sDom": "<t><'row'<p i>>",
            "destroy": true,
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ ",
                "sInfo": "Showing <b>_START_ to _END_</b> of _TOTAL_ entries"
            },
            "iDisplayLength": 5
        };

        show_list();
        table.dataTable(settings);

        // search box for table
        $('#search-table').keyup(function() {
            table.fnFilter($(this).val());
        });
    }

    initTableWithSearch();

    function show_list(){
            $.ajax({
                type        : 'ajax',
                url         : '<?php echo site_url('visi/data_list')?>',
                async       : true,
                dataType    : 'json',
                success     : function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    var no = 1;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        if (data[i].is_deleted == 'n') {
                            data[i].is_deleted = 'NO';
                        } else {
                            data[i].is_deleted = 'YES';
                        }
                        html += '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>'+no+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].name+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].detail+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+data[i].is_deleted+'</td>'+
                                    '<td style="text-align: right;">'+
                                        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-list_id="'+data[i].id+'" data-list_name="'+data[i].name+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                                        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-list_id="'+data[i].id+'">Delete</a>'+
                                    '</td>'+
                                '<tr>';
                                no++;
                    }
                    $('#show_data').html(html);
                }
            });
        }

        // function 

})(window.jQuery); ```
````

````html
```<table class="table table-hover demo-table-search table-responsive-block" id="tableWithSearch">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>No.</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Detail</th>
                      <th>Deleted?</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="show_data">
                    <!-- <tr>
                      <td class="v-align-middle semi-bold">
                        <p>First Tour</p>
                      </td>
                      <td class="v-align-middle"><a href="#" class="btn btn-tag">United States</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-tag">India</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-tag">China</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-tag">Africa</a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="v-align-middle">
                        <p>it is more then ONE nation/nationality as its fall name is The United Kingdom of Great Britain and North Ireland..</p>
                      </td>
                      <td class="v-align-middle">
                        <p>Public</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr> -->
                  </tbody>
                </table>```
````

the data before
  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/34QDA.png)
the data disappears after type on search
  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r5ne.png)

thank you

Comment: What clues do you have in your browser's developer tools? Any client-side errors? What does that url return exactly? What is in the XHR tab of your dev tools?  What does the generated source code look like?

Comment: You must insert data using the API, or simply use the retrieved data as dataSrc. Why not place the ajax inside DT settings? Since you add "rows" (i.e plain markup) using jQuery, DataTables have no chance to search within the data. It simply does not know that you have added the markup ...